# How do I move the "exit" button so that it's in the top right corner of my modal box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

Details:
I have a background image, and I have a square image that I made in Illustrator that I want to place on top. (This is acting as the button that will open the modal window) However, the "close" button for the modal window is appearing below my background image rather than in the top right corner of the modal window. I'm new to HTML/CSS and any help is appreciated!

This is my style.css:

```
div {
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

.home {
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

.city1 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 350px;
   left: 40px;
}

#overlay {
   visibility: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   z-index: 1000;
}

#overlay div {
   width: 600px;
   height: 600px;
   top: 300px;
   left: 220px;
   background-color: #FFF;
   padding: 15px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

This is my test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src="popUp.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
   <div>
      <img src="background.jpg" alt="homeScreen" class="home"/>
      <div id="overlay">
         <div>
            <img src="" alt="province1"/>
         </div>
      </div>

      <img src="city1.png" class="city1" onclick='overlay()'></a>
   </div>
      <a href='#' onclick='overlay()'><img src="exit.png" class="exit"/></a>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my popUp.js:

```
function overlay() {
   el= document.getElementById("overlay");
   el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
```

Comment: I made this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld7Lbqd1/) with your code, but with the lack of images it is very difficult to understand what's happening and eventually suggest a solution. If you could, please add some images so its easier for anyone to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have background image then use CSS background-image property on a proper div instead of putting `<img src="background.jpg" alt="homeScreen" class="home"/>` inside it.
Closing icon should be visible then and you'll be able to play with CSS positioning of it, as you've made e.g. with `home` class.

Comment: Thank you! Could you possibly show me the code for it? Sorry, I'm still learning and it's hard to visualize this!

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, you should place the `<a href='#' onclick='overlay()'><img src="exit.png" class="exit"/></a>` within the overlay `<div>`. Then, moving the icon to the top right corner is a matter of applying the right CSS properties, e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp